# Dubiety About An Inequality Proof

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, proof-verification

In Principles of Mathematical Analysis, the author is attempting to demonstrate that, if $x>0$ and $y<z$, then $xy<xz$, which essentially states that multiplying by a positive number does not disturb the inequality.

I feel as though the author is using the very result he is endeavoring to prove, but I am hoping someone will quickly denounce this with an adequate explanation.

He begins by noting that, if $z>y$, $z−y>0$. He multiplies both sides by $x>0$, and gets $x(z−y)>0$.

This seems to be a special case of the theorem which we are trying to prove. Wouldn't this be an invalid step as we do not know what results from multiplying both sides of an inequality? Let c=z−y, and replace y with zero in the theorem. This would give us

If $x>0$ and $0<c$, then $x⋅0<xc$.

Am I mistaken?

Comment: It depends on how he defines $x>y$, I suppose, but most books start by proving the product of two positive real numbers is a positive real number. In which case, he'd have proved the special case already.

Comment: Let $z, y$ be real numbers. Then $z > y$ means $z - y > 0.$ I think this is the usual definition.

Comment: Whoops, he specifies that $xy > 0$ if $x \in F$, $y \in F$, where $F$ is an ordered field, and $x >0$ and $y > 0$...I reckon more careful reading elucidates all answers...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about where exactly you got stuck. But $z \gt y \Leftarrow \Rightarrow z -y\gt0$. Then you apply the distributive law by multiplying $z-y$ by $x$.